# Chrome extensions close all tabs without certain div

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm having a lot of trouble with Chrome Extensions, im trying to close all open tabs that do not contain a certain class.

This is the general idea of what i am trying to do, some of it is pseudo-code.

```
//background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query(function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
                var existsClass = request[i].getElementByClass("someClass");
                if (existClass === null) {
                    //TODO Close tab
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your second snippet is from a content script.

In that case, it's as simple as `window.close()`, because you're in that tab's context. No need for Chrome APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {  //when the extension's icon is pressed
  chrome.tabs.query({},function(tabs) {  // get all tabs
    for (var i = tabs.length; i--;){     // loop through all tabs
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id,{code:  //execute this code in each tab
        "if (!document.querySelector(\".someClass\")) close();"});
       // ^ if no element is found with the selected class, close the tab
    }
  });
});
```

You don't need a separate content script for that.